# Find Possible fits of a template contour in a bigger contour (opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working with C++ and opencv. There is a problem that I am trying to solve concerning contours detected in an image. The source images are converted in binary ones like those shown below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB9lE.png

The regions inside the red rectangle are the ones that interest me.

An example of the contour that can be used as a template is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc9Hl.png

I would like to find a way to isolate the region shown inside the red rectangle. One idea is to try to find all the possible (best) ways that the template contour can fit inside the source contours shown above. In that manner I will reject the ones that does not have the appropriate characteristics such as the desirable gradient.

Any ideas guidance or ideas would be helpful.

Apostolos

Comment: Have you tried [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)?

Comment: I have checked this solution but I think that is something that concern more complex pictures.

Comment: Finally today I checked the template matching but there are difficulties because the angle of the template has to be almost the same in order to find it. I have to find a way to distinguish the template from the unwanted area. Any Ideas?

Comment: I have also tested the matchShapes function which is not working for me.

Comment: Maybe you could try [SIFT](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-introduction/) and SURF algorithms which account for rotations but this is probably a bit overkill for what you want to achieve. [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html) is the opencv documentaion.